# Custom font not Showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to add custom font in my application . I am adding in my project.
and then adding in .plist file.

[image: plist file]

[image: Resources]

and my code is

```
 UIFont *CiutadellaBold = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Light up the World with accented characters" size:90.0f];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [label setFont:CiutadellaBold];
    label.text =@"hello";
```

But the text does not show up in my custom font. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use font's postscript name, not the font's file name.

Comment: @JitendraGandhi that is not true. You should add file name in your info.plist

Comment: Oh yes.. we need to add file name in info.plist..!!

Answer (score 2):

The name of your font is most likely not identical to file name. You can find out names of fonts available in app like this:

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", family);
    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:family])
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your font name is not equals to the file name, you should get in in file info
[image]

Comment: Full name as displayed in file info is not always identical to the name of font you need to use inside app. For example Roboto Bold as found at http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/download/roboto

Answer (score 0):

First check your font is installed in "Font Book" application in your mac. copy the "postScript name" and use in your code.

```
 UIFont *CiutadellaBold = [UIFont fontWithName:@"postScript name" size:90.0f];
```

Please refer attached screen shot.[image]

Note:This is for iPhoneSimulator. You also check this in device. Sometime this issue not occur in device.